# Unable to write to Excel sheet in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, excel, selenium

This is the code I used for writing two strings to an Excel sheet. But I am getting this error : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (no sheets)`

```
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\151680\\workspace\\trial.xlsx"));
      XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
      XSSFSheet sh1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
      sh1.getRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("abc");
      sh1.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("def");
      wb.write(fout);
```

Currently there is no workbook called trial.xlsx in the given path. When this code is run its supposed to create the workbook right? Or do I have to create and keep one in the path? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No excelsheet is created because you get the exception. If you want to create an excel sheet you have to call `wb.createSheet()` insteat of `wb.getSheetAt(0);`

```
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\151680\\workspace\\trial.xlsx"));
      XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
      XSSFSheet sh1=wb.createSheet();
      XSSFRow row = sh1.createtRow(0);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("abc");
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue("def");
      wb.write(fout);
      fout.close();
```

Comment: I have changed my answer you have also to create row(0) before you can create a cell